# WebStorm 2016.3 cannot show Git log

Tags: git, webstorm

Git log is shown well in WebStorm 2016.2 and built-in GUI of Git. However, WebStorm 2016.3 cannot show the log, just keep running forever. I tried to reinstall both WebStorm and Git, but no luck for me.
I also tried on another PC, then WS2016.3 shows Git log normally.

[Screenshot 2016.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbkJV.png)

[Screenshot 2016.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHEfm.png)

Comment: You probably need to report your issue to JetBrains issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on `log`, right side of `Local Changes`

```
Version Control: LocalChanges -> Log
```

Comment: It's just a mistake in taking a screenshot. As I said, it keep running all day.